# running a python file in Xcode gives the following error: Command ExternalBuildToolExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: python, xcode10, macos-mojave

A few days ago I got a mac and I wanted to try out Xcode 10. When I run a python file in Xcode I get the folowing error:

```
Command ExternalBuildToolExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

What can  I do to resolve this error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup to project to run on External Build Tool?

Checkout this manual:
[running-python-in-xcode-step-by-step](https://ericasadun.com/2016/12/04/running-python-in-xcode-step-by-step/)

Comment: No, I will try now

Comment: Did you setup the build tool to the correct python path?

Comment: Hoe do you do that?